# Automatically breaking lines in comments?

Tags: line-breaks

Vim has the excellent command `set tw=79` which will automatically break your lines at 79 characters, however I like (just) my comments broken at 72 characters automatically.

Is there any good way to do this in Vim?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like this one

```
augroup comment_textwidth
    autocmd!
    autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI * :call AdjustTextWidth()
augroup END

function! AdjustTextWidth()
    let syn_element = synIDattr(synID(line("."), col(".") - 1, 1), "name")
    let &textwidth = syn_element =~? 'comment' ? 72 : 79
    echo "tw = " . &textwidth
endfunction
```

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3kk4ml/settings_a_different_textwidth_for_comments/)

For more inspiration look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027222/vim-use-shorter-textwidth-in-comments-and-docstrings).

Comment: Funny thing is, I never thought of that solution as a serious one :)

Comment: If it works, it works :)